Implications of different name servers at registrar and hosting company
This is basically an "if it seems to be working OK can I safely leave it alone" question. I'm pretty sure it's wrong, lol, but can I leave it? Here are the details.
I'm trying to set up a temporary site/landing page for my ex-boss. He's going to have a Wordpress site hosted at some Wordpress-y provider, soon/eventually; this is basically an HTML "coming soon" page, with an email sign-up.
We have similar setups:

Both have domains we haven't been using for websites previously.
Using Google workspace for mail and
Registrar is GoDaddy

A couple of weeks ago I paid for a few months of shared Windows hosting ASPHostPortal. My thought was to set my domain up there and hopefully not trash my email in the process, so I could duplicate those settings for his site/coming soon page up. Since it is only going to live here for a month or three, I thought I'd leave everything DNS-wise at GoDaddy.
I've only ever worked on a dedicated server and mostly just manually transferred the domain settings when changing servers, and then changed the nameservers at GoDaddy. The current set-up is with Plesk; I've never used a control panel in my life. lol.
I logged into Plesk for the first time today to start figuring things out with my domain first, and I noticed a slew of existing DNS records, including NS and MX records. I don't know why this was a surprise to me but...it was. I guess it's partly because I think I specifically unchecked a box about setting up email when signing up.
GoDaddy (only) has an SOA entry. My Workspace email (MX records at GoDaddy only) has worked fine the past couple of weeks. I changed my GoDaddy A record from "Parked" to pointing at the ASPHostPortal IP address, uploaded an index.html file with "Nothing here yet" on it, and it worked as expected.
If it is OK that things are set up this way, that's great! I'll just do the same to ex-boss's, and he/we can look at more permanent changes when his WP site is set up. And if that's the case, do I need to/should I delete any mail-related records from asphostportal, or does it matter?
domain.com MX mail.domain.com
mail.domain.com.        A   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
webmail.domain.com.     A   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Conversely, if I'm going to run into problems...any way to just do alllll the DNS at GoDaddy? Just copy whatever records seem necessary to GoDaddy?

That DNS looks like a standard cpanel setup and will work fine.

From a technical POV, as asked, this post is missing too much information to allow an answer.   When it comes to working through where DNS resolves the key thing to is to look at NS records (including both with the registrar and in the zone as these are not synonomous).  A domain with only an SOA entry can't be resolved - so somewhere something is injecting NS records - quite possibly Godaddy.

When dealing with authorative only DNS servers (which you most likely are here) wrong/outdated information on servers which are not authorative won't have a practical impact, so leaving behind DNS records won't kill anything - although its not a best practice.

@davidgo Why don't you make that an answer, and I'll accept it. The GoDaddy DNS records (because it has the SOA) are being followed, and the hosting company is ignored. (e.g. ftp.mydomain.com doesn't work, as I didn't add it to GoDaddy.) However, Plesk appears to use the hosting companies DNS records in order to add Let's Encrypt certs, so some of those records did need to exist. It's a weird setup, which I wouldn't recommend, but will work well for me since whoever does the WP site can just handle all the final DNS changes on the new server without any intervention from me. :)

The reason that your registrar and your web host have different NS records is that both of them are offering to be your DNS host. Since you can only have one DNS host, there are going to be record mismatches.
Given that you are editing A records at your registrar, you have chosen your registrar to host your DNS.  That is a fine choice, but it means that your web host won't be able to make DNS changes automatically on your behalf. You will have to manually enter any DNS records that your web host suggests into your registrar's DNS system.
It isn't SOA records that specify who hosts your DNS, it is the NS records.  If you wanted to use your web host's DNS services, you could have to set the nameserver (NS) records at Godaddy to the NS values in your web host's DNS system.  Godaddy has instructions for that here: https://www.godaddy.com/help/edit-my-domain-nameservers-664 where you would have to select "I'll use my own nameservers".
Here is a diagram that illustrates how DNS records work for a website and email server:


Thanks! I know most of that, and normally just set the NS to the web host. I thought that the having SOA record at GoDaddy meant it would use that set of DNS records, but I guess it stores the primary nameserver server URL? But it seems to be working, a few minor issues involving Plesk certificates and having to use IP for FTP instead of ftp.mydomain.com. It's temporary, and (hopefully, as I don't know WP) someone else will be setting up his live website, and will have the correct Workspace, email marketing app, etc. records to add without my involvement.
